# How to decrypt an openssl_encrypt() encrypted value using MySQL query?

Tags: php, mysql, encryption, pdo, aes

If I am using the following PHP script to encrypt a field in my database:

```
<?php
require_once('../api.php');

$newApi = new api();
$conn = $newApi->connection();

//$key previously generated safely, ie: openssl_random_pseudo_bytes
$plaintext = "Test";
$key="testKey";
$ivlen = openssl_cipher_iv_length($cipher="AES-128-CBC");
$iv = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes($ivlen);
$ciphertext_raw = openssl_encrypt($plaintext, $cipher, $key, $options=OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $iv);
$hmac = hash_hmac('sha256', $ciphertext_raw, $key, $as_binary=true);
$ciphertext = base64_encode( $iv.$hmac.$ciphertext_raw );

echo $ciphertext;
$sql = 'INSERT INTO test(encName) VALUES(:enc)';
$exec=$conn->prepare($sql);
$exec->bindValue(':enc', $ciphertext);
$exec->execute();

echo "\n";
$c = base64_decode($ciphertext);
$hmac = substr($c, $ivlen, $sha2len=32);
$ciphertext_raw = substr($c, $ivlen+$sha2len);
$original_plaintext = openssl_decrypt($ciphertext_raw, $cipher, $key, $options=OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $iv);
$calcmac = hash_hmac('sha256', $ciphertext_raw, $key, $as_binary=true);
if (hash_equals($hmac, $calcmac))//PHP 5.6+ timing attack safe comparison
{
    echo $original_plaintext."\n";
}

$sql = "SELECT aes_decrypt(encName, 'testKey') FROM test";
$exec = $conn->prepare($sql);
$exec->execute();
$res=$exec->fetchAll();
foreach($res as $result)
{
    print_r($result);
    echo "\n";
}
```

As you see, I used:

```
SELECT aes_decrypt(encName, 'testKey') FROM test
```

to retrieve the original name. But it didn't work. Apparently, `openssl_encrypt()` doesn't have any equivalent in MySQL.

I tried to understand this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49236781/php-openssl-decrypt-an-aes-mysql-encryption):

> In mysql the full length key is used by AES_ENCRYPT() and
>   AES_DECRYPT()
>
> ```
> SELECT 
> HEX(AES_ENCRYPT('testvalue',UNHEX(SHA2('mysecretphrase',512)))) AS l_full,
> HEX(AES_ENCRYPT('testvalue',SUBSTR(UNHEX(SHA2('mysecretphrase',512)),1,16)))
>
> AS l_16,
> HEX(AES_ENCRYPT('testvalue',SUBSTR(UNHEX(SHA2('mysecretphrase',512)),1,15)))
>
> AS l_15;
> ```

But the point is to encrypt using PHP and decrypt using PHP or MYSQL.

How to retrieve the original value of the field `encName` using a MySQL query? And do I use the second method where I used aes_encrypt() and decrypt() inside the MySQL query?

Comment: Hash the contents or use another key before encryption if you need to have a id field for querying, then decrypt using php rather than mysql.

Comment: No. Sometimes I need to search by name.

Comment: Encrypting or output format are different between openssl and mysq, so you cannot just interchange them. https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2012/05/replicating-mysql-aes-encryption-methods-with-php/